# FirebaseError permission denied when all permissions allowed (emulator)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

When using Firebase web client + NodeJS Firebase functions (authentication, Firestore, Functions), I, **sometimes**, receive this error:

> {"code":"permission-denied","name":"FirebaseError"} FirebaseError:
> [code=permission-denied]: PERMISSION_DENIED:  Service call error.
> Function: [get], Argument: [path_value {   segments {
> simple: "databases"   }   segments {
> simple: "(default)"   }   segments {
> simple: "documents"   }   segments {
> simple: "users"   }   segments {
> simple: "NKF7rdfahWGlKKPtyoVJ0egyYF6k"   } } ]. for 'create' @ L12

However, everything is allowed:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {

        match /users/{userId} {
            allow read, write: if true;
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes I just restart processes and everything works again...

I start emulator with
`npm run build -- --watch | firebase emulators:start`

I tried to set all rules to read, write true, no better success, any idea of the problem?

Firebase CLI: 9.16.5

Functions: firebase-admin: 9.11.0

Client: firebase: 8.10.0

Comment: Just to confirm, you are editing rules in local firestore rules file right? Because that's what Firestore emulator will be looking for instead of the rules in prodcution

Comment: Yes. Actually, it is probably this https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3258#issuecomment-814402977

Comment: yes that problem with the emulator have been there for a couple of weeks, could you please tell us if you still have the issue with the version Firestore JS SDK v8.3.1? you can also try to use the Firebase CLI v9.9.0. that looks like the problem is solved there

Answer (score 1):

As [@Robertocd-98](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15747932/robertocd-98) proposed, **using firebase sdk 8.3.1 solved the problem.**